# Logic of if statement only reaches 9/10

Tags: javascript, if-statement, numbers

The code is supposed to award the majority of 10 flips to the winner coin side.
However it is only going to 9 flips and rewarding the majority out of the 9.

I have tried tempering around the numbers, but none have succeeded. upon changing the percentage to 110 the total flips only goes to 7

```
    //start decleration of variables; self explainitory 
    var placeholder = document.getElementById("placeholder");
    var heads_counter = 0;
    var tails_counter = 0;
    var wins = 10;

    //reset button listener & functionality 
    document.getElementById("reset").addEventListener("click", function(){
        heads_counter = 0;
        tails_counter = 0;
        placeholder.innerText = ("");
        coin_placeholder.innerText = ("");
    });

    //coin img event listener & functionality 
    document.getElementById("coin").addEventListener("click", function(){
        //50% chance of 1 or 2
        var chance = Math.floor(Math.random() * 2); 

        //if chance is 1 "Heads!"" is displayed in place holder and adds to heads_counter
        if (chance == 1){
            placeholder.innerText = ("Heads!");
            heads_counter++;                
        //else statment if chance is 2, "Tails!" is displayed and adds to tails_counter 
        }else  {
            placeholder.innerText = ("Tails!");
            tails_counter++;        
        }
        //if the majority of total flips is heads, "Heads wins!" is displayed
        if(51 <= heads_counter / wins * 100 && tails_counter / wins * 100 <= 49){
            placeholder.innerText = ("Heads Wins!");
            heads_counter = 0;
            tails_counter = 0;
        //if the majority of total flips is tails, "Tails wins!" is displayed
        }else if (51 <= tails_counter / wins * 100  && heads_counter / wins * 100 <= 49){
            placeholder.innerText = ("Tails Wins!");
            heads_counter = 0;
            tails_counter = 0;
        //if flips are tied, "Tie!" is displayed
        }else if(tails_counter / wins * 100 == 50 && heads_counter / wins * 100 == 50){
            placeholder.innerText = ("Tie!")
            heads_counter = 0;
            tails_counter = 0;
        }
        //innerText of coin_placeholder
        coin_placeholder.innerText = ("Heads: " + heads_counter + " Tails: " + tails_counter);
});
```

Comment: Please post a [mcve].

Comment: the code you posted doesn't even do ONE flip, so - wrong code posted

Comment: not all of the code is pasted

Comment: yes, but the code you pasted is not at all relevant to the issue you are having

Comment: Never mind; the problem is that if you throw heads 6 times, the first check is already true. So in theory it will end the game after 6 throws occasionally.

Comment: updated all the code

Comment: Just wrap the checks at the bottom in `if (tails_counter + heads_counts === wins)` You also don't need those complicated percent checks just to figure out who won. Just do `if (heads_counter > tails_counter)` etc

Comment: if I did heads_counter > tails_counter results in win wouldn't someone win as soon as one flip was calculated?

Comment: Reread the first sentence of my comment

Comment: you are right, post that as a answer I will check it

Comment: classic case of overthinking the problem when the solution is so much simpler

Comment: You may want to stop using 51 in your definition of majority, because it will give incorrect results for large populations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The coin flip is not happening ten times.

Your logic in the second `if` statement is effectively looking for 5 or more flips on one side, but does not check for the required remainder. I.e. 6 heads will win and end the game, even if there is only 1 tails.

This is because the greater than and the less than requirements do not necessarily add up to 100%, i.e. 6 heads and 3 tails would match these requirements as 60% would be heads and 30% would be tails (i.e. >50% heads and <50% tails).

I've added a basic check, and exited the function before this check if the overall limit hasn't been met.

---

## Demo

```js
//start decleration of variables; self explainitory 
var placeholder = document.getElementById("placeholder");
var coin_placeholder = document.getElementById("coin_placeholder");
var heads_counter = 0;
var tails_counter = 0;
var wins = 10;

//reset button listener & functionality 
document.getElementById("reset").addEventListener("click", function() {
  heads_counter = 0;
  tails_counter = 0;
  placeholder.innerText = ("");
  coin_placeholder.innerText = ("");
});

//coin img event listener & functionality 
document.getElementById("coin").addEventListener("click", function() {
  //50% chance of 1 or 2
  var chance = Math.floor(Math.random() * 2);

  //if chance is 1 "Heads!"" is displayed in place holder and adds to heads_counter
  if (chance == 1) {
    placeholder.innerText = ("Heads!");
    heads_counter++;
    //else statment if chance is 2, "Tails!" is displayed and adds to tails_counter 
  } else {
    placeholder.innerText = ("Tails!");
    tails_counter++;
  }

  //innerText of coin_placeholder
  coin_placeholder.innerText = ("Heads: " + heads_counter + " Tails: " + tails_counter);
  
   // Check if total coin flips matches the required number of wins, exit function if it does not
   if ( heads_counter + tails_counter < wins ) {
      return;
   }

  //if the majority of total flips is heads, "Heads wins!" is displayed
  if (50 < heads_counter / wins * 100 && tails_counter / wins * 100 < 50 ) {
    placeholder.innerText = ("Heads Wins!");
    //if the majority of total flips is tails, "Tails wins!" is displayed
  } else if (50 < tails_counter / wins * 100 && heads_counter / wins * 100 < 50 ) {
    placeholder.innerText = ("Tails Wins!");
    //if flips are tied, "Tie!" is displayed
  } else if (tails_counter / wins * 100 == 50 && heads_counter / wins * 100 == 50 ) {
    placeholder.innerText = ("Tie!")
  }
  
  // This can come out of the if statement above now\
  // Reset counters
  heads_counter = 0;
  tails_counter = 0;
  
});
```

```html
<p id="placeholder"></p>
<p id="coin_placeholder"></p>

<button id="reset">Reset</button>
<button id="coin">Coin</button>
```

Comment: "Majority" does not mean "51% or more."  It means "more than 50%."